# Are there resources that provide collections of good math training activities?

Tags: education, games, math

I am very eager to access collections of good math training activities, games, etc -- hopefully high quality and aligned with current curriculum movements like common core, etc.

Naturally I would prefer free but if the collection was excellent I would pay.

Where can I acquire respirces, activities, games, for math? My daughter is six years old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out Khan Academy, Math Mammoth, Saxon, Abeka, Singapore, Math-U-See, and Miquon.  Those are the major curricula used by homeschoolers.  The leap pad 2 tablets have some nice math games, and there are tons of apps for iPad and Android if you search the app stores.  You can find a lot of individual activities by searching pinterest or teacherspayteachers.com.

Being common core aligned is another issue.  People in my circles (we homeschool and have a few relatives who teach public school) mostly don't like common core math, at least for the younger grades, so most of the resources are more geared toward schools than individual families.  If you're homeschooling, you can choose something better.  If you're supplementing, I guess it depends what your goals are and how your children learn best.